# ¿Como crear preguntas y según (SI y NO) hacer X acción? en javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Lo estoy haciendo así pero me sigue haciendo las preguntas del IF si le doy cancelar o NO.

```js
if (confirm("ERES CAPAZ DE HACER 1 FLEXION")) {
            if (confirm("HASTA 5 FLEXIONES?")) {
                
            } else {
                window.location = "Fase2.html";
            }
            if (confirm("MAS DE 5 DOMINADAS Y 5 FONDOS EN PARALELAS")) {

            } else {

            }
        } else {
            window.location = "Fase1.html";
        }
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar desde acá y desde JSFiddle y está funcionando bien.

Comment: Funciona pero no hace lo que quiero, fíjate que en la segunda pregunta si le doy "Cancelar" me sigue haciendo las demás preguntas en ves de entrar en el "Else". Quizá es un error fácil de arreglar pero soy principiante en Javascript jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está *casi* bien lo que estás haciendo. El problemas es que el `window.location` demora y por eso te aparece la segunda pregunta. Esa segunda pregunta debería estar dentro del primer `if`, no debajo del `else`.

```js
if (confirm("ERES CAPAZ DE HACER 1 FLEXION")) {
    if (confirm("HASTA 5 FLEXIONES?")) {
        if (confirm("MAS DE 5 DOMINADAS Y 5 FONDOS EN PARALELAS")) {

        } else {

        }
    } else {
        window.location = "Fase2.html";
    }
} else {
    window.location = "Fase1.html";
}
```

Si el código está dentro de una función, para evitar que el código siga después de un `window.location` podes hacer un `return false`.

```js
function preguntas() {
    if (confirm("ERES CAPAZ DE HACER 1 FLEXION")) {
        if (confirm("HASTA 5 FLEXIONES?")) {
            if (confirm("MAS DE 5 DOMINADAS Y 5 FONDOS EN PARALELAS")) {

            } else {

            }
        } else {
            window.location = "Fase2.html";
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        window.location = "Fase1.html";
        return false;
    }
}

preguntas();
```